# Displaying consistent time regardless of time zone using JavaScript/MomentJS

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

Having a problem working with dates stored as time stamps (milliseconds since epoch) where I have the time stamp and the timezone for an event, but JavaScript/MomentJS is displaying the time with what appears to be the incorrect offset.

For the sake of brevity here is the type of object I have:

```
    {
       "name" : "Something happening",
       "timezone" : "America/Los_Angeles",
       "start" : 1586631607338
    }
```

The above event is being held in Los Angeles, CA, the date ('`start`'). The event was saved to the database by a browser in Eastern Daylight Time. So, in the browser that created this event, the time is correct.

When the browser's time zone is changed (from EDT to PDT) the above event's time is now 3 hours earlier.

Which is not accurate, the event needs to display the correct time for the start of the event, which in this example is supposed to be `3:00 PM` but is being displayed as `12:00 PM`

Basically, if the user is in LA, they will see this event with a start time of `12:00 PM` but the author defined the start time as `3:00 PM`

Using MomentJS, the date for each event is translated into a UTC timestamp and written to the database

On the authoring side, we have code which basically does:

```
// event.startTime is an instance of a JS Date object
var startTime = moment(event.startTime.getTime()).utc().valueOf();
// startTime is now a UTC time stamp
```

The `startTime` is written to the database along with the event's time zone.

On the front-end/display we do:

```
var startTime = moment.tz(event.startTime, event.timezone);
// startTime is now a MomentJS object, which we then use format()
```

On the author's side, they have created an event for 3:00 PM, it shows up in their event detail screen as starting at 3:00 PM.

But a user in LA will see this event as starting at 12:00 PM

The goal is to show this event as starting at 3:00 PM no matter where the user is, in that the event's date should read:

3:00 PM - 5:00 PM PDT but reads as: 12:00 PM - 2:00 PM PDT

It was my understanding that storing a UTC timestamp with a time zone meant avoid this exact issue, but something is going wrong somewhere. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`moment(event.startTime.getTime()).utc().valueOf()` is going to be equal to `event.startTime.getTime()` because the `getTime` function of the `Date` object returns a Unix timestamp (in terms of milliseconds), and Unix timestamps are always UTC based.  Switching from Moment's local mode to UTC mode doesn't changing the underlying timestamp, thus you aren't really doing much here.

Let's look at the timestamp you gave, in the various contexts that apply here:

```
moment.utc(1586631607338).format()                        //=> "2020-04-11T19:00:07Z"
moment.tz(1586631607338, 'America/New_York').format()     //=> "2020-04-11T15:00:07-04:00"
moment.tz(1586631607338, 'America/Los_Angeles').format()  //=> "2020-04-11T12:00:07-07:00"
```

As you can see, this UTC timestamp represents 3 PM in Eastern Time, and noon in Pacific Time.  (You also have an extra `7338` milliseconds in your timestamp, you might want to round off.)

If you wanted a timestamp to represent 3 PM in Pacific Time on that day, it would be `1586642407338`:

```
moment.utc(1586642407338).format()                        //=> "2020-04-11T22:00:07Z"
moment.tz(1586642407338, 'America/New_York').format()     //=> "2020-04-11T18:00:07-04:00"
moment.tz(1586642407338, 'America/Los_Angeles').format()  //=> "2020-04-11T15:00:07-07:00"
```

It seems to me that the problem you have is that you are starting from a `Date` object that is generated by the local time of the browser.  Likely from a date/time picker of some sorts. Many of these pickers have been written to return an ISO 8601 string instead of a `Date` object because of this very problem. You'll also find that the ones built-in to the browser with HTML5's `<input type="date" />` and `<input type="datetime-local" />` also use strings instead of `Date` objects.  There are also a few pickers that are based on Moment and have time zone settings - so you do have options in this regard.

However, if you don't want to change your picker, then you can cheat by adjusting for the time zones on the way in:

```
var startTime = moment(event.startTime).tz(event.timezone, true).valueOf();
```

The key part here is the `true` flag passed to the `tz` instance function's `keepTime` parameter.  It provides similar behavior as the in the `utcOffset` instance function, but with a named time zone instead of a fixed offset.  The [docs for that](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) describe as follows:

> The `utcOffset` function has an optional second parameter which accepts
>   a boolean value indicating whether to keep the existing time of day.
>
> - Passing `false` (the default) will keep the same instant in Universal
>     Time, but the local time will change.
> - Passing `true` will keep the same local time, but at the expense of
>     choosing a different point in Universal Time.

There is [missing documentation](https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com/issues/586) about this on the `tz` function, but it works the same way, and will help create the correct timestamp for your scenario.

The disadvantage of "cheating" this way, is that your user will be unable to pick a time that falls into a DST gap in their local time zone, even if it is valid in the event's time zone.  For example, 2 AM on 2020-03-08 is invalid in `America/New_York`, but is perfectly fine in `America/Phoenix`.  A picker that doesn't use `Date` objects will allow this, but "cheating" in the way I described above will not.

Comment: Marked this as the answer. The date picker widget was indeed providing a Date object, and had no idea about the additional boolean flag on the tz() function. Thank you!